# How long will the dark events in xcom 2 stay active?

Tags: xcom-2

Some of the dark events (e.g. Fast Response - additional reinforcements in Guerilla missions) become active after a while - how long do they stay active?

Comment: I've been playing for over two months (in-game, ofc) and I've not yet seen one dissapear; my theory is that they don't dissapear until countered.

Comment: I know at least one of them (the one where Faceless appear on all missions) specifically says something like "Faceless will appear for the next month". Not sure if they all have that or not.

Comment: @ChrisHayes Actually, yes, I'm stupid, I have seen evidence of them disappearing.

Answer (score 6):

The dark event should say itself. (Though obviously, some, such as the Resistance Mole event, are instantaneous, and have no duration at all).

Generally, for the ones with duration, they last a month.